Set Thunderbird "Local Directory" path on ubuntu 24.04
I need to change the Thunderbird 128.2.3esr (64-bit) "Local Directory" path to something within my backup zone in my home folder.
On previous Ubuntu 22.04, Thunderbird comes by deb package and it was possible to alter that setting.
Unfortunately, on Ubuntu 24.04, Thunderbird comes as snap, and it does not let me change that path in edit -> account settings -> local directory -> browse. After changing the path, Thunderbird should tell me the change will be effective after reboot, instead the path is the same as before, ignoring the one I selected on the browser window.

See answer at the following link: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528030/thunderbird-will-not-create-profile-in-chosen-folder-on-a-different-partition/1528043#1528043

Since Thunderbird shows the path to "Local Directory" folder, I replaced the last folder of that path with a symbolic link to the real folder within my backup zone.
