Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, Thunderbird is Not Opening
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my new laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad).
I noticed that Thunderbird is not available in the existing applications list (which was quite strange, as previously Thunderbird was always in the list of default installed apps).
So I opened the App Center and installed the Thunderbird. Installation was finished successfully, however once I am trying to open the Thunderbird - it shows loading indicator on the Thunderbird icon in the left menu panel, but nothing is opened.
When I am doing a right click on the Thunderbird icon, and choosing "All Windows" - in the popup it shows that the page for setting up an account is opened - but when I click on the popup in order to open that page - again nothing is opened.
So I am not sure what is the issue with it, and that is Quite Strange that in the LTS version such an issue exist with the main email client that is used in the Ubuntu.
Anyone knows what is going on, and is there any way to fix it??

Thunderbird has switched to a snap default. Thunderbird stores the account in a different location. See the following answer for some details. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528030/thunderbird-will-not-create-profile-in-chosen-folder-on-a-different-partition/1528043#1528043 The snap should run though so I am not sure why you can't see any windows at all.
